# How to change scan type / field order in video's metadata?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, metadata

VLC plays my 50i H.264 MOV incorrectly when I try to do Deinterlace = on and Deinterlace mode = Yadif 2x. The video is jumpy like crazy. Looks like it's detecting the field order incorrectly. So what I'd like to do is to force a meta tag for the video file, saying Interlaced as Scan type and either Upper or Lower for the Scan order. I was able to write Upper/Lower with `exiftool -videofieldorder=upper INPUT.MOV` but that didn't make any difference in VLC or MediaInfo. Also I tried many parameters with ffmpeg, such as `ffmpeg -i INPUT.MOV -field_order bb -vcodec copy -acodec copy OUTPUT.MOV` but this made exactly same result when changing bb to tt so it didn't add any bottom or top information that way at all.

So in Windows, how do I change the Scan type/order metadata for a video file so that I could get it working smoothly in VLC (when Deinterlace on and Yadif 2x on in VLC)?

By the way, what does it mean when MediaInfo says "Scan type: Progressive" but still "Scan order: Bottom Field First" for some files? This is logically an impossible combination, right?

Comment: I recommend testing the different modes of yadif with `ffplay`. Example `ffplay -vf yadif=1:1 input`. See the [yadif docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif-1) for more info.

Comment: Nice suggestion. For my particular video, `ffplay -vf yadif=1:0 video.mov` worked and it played the video quite smoothly. Is there no way to change the metadata in Windows? I didn't try, but I think for Mac I could use JES Extensifier.